# Select values based on database result

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have a form with a multi select which presents the user with a list of groups to chose from,which is then saved in the database. My aim is that when the user wants to edit his information, the groups saved in the database to be selected and the others not to be selected. Please, see my code and advise.

I populate the saved groups to a variable

```
$groups = array($row['groups']); // This outputs the groupId from the db eg 1,2,3,6
```

Populate groups to a multi select

```
<div class="form-group">
     <!-- <label>Church Groups: </label> -->
     <select name="groups[]" class="form-control mandatory" id="groups" multiple="multiple" >
         <?php
             $sql="SELECT ID,UCASE(groupName) AS groupName FROM tblgroups WHERE (congregationId=?)";
             $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($con);
             mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$congId);
             mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
             $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                 $selected = "";
                 if(in_array($row['ID'],$groups)){ 
                     $selected = "selected"; 
                 }
                 echo '<option value='.$row['ID'].' '.$selected.'>'.$row['groupName'].'</option>';
             }
          ?>
     </select>
```

Thats my code but it doesn't work. If the first group in the list was saved, only that group is selected all others **remain unselected** whether in the db or not.

Comment: what is the value of `print_r($result);`

Comment: I would avoid fragmenting the `echo option` part in all those `<?php` sections. It makes the code very difficult to read, and it is more difficult to detect any mistakes.

Comment: I agree with @Roberto. Why can't you just use echo to display the html as opposed to switching between php and html? Like that the code is hard to read.

Comment: the `print_r($result);` is `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 13 [type] => 0 )`

Comment: @Kasalwe , am learning so please provide a better way for doing this or edit the code for better understanding

Comment: @Nick, the code that you have commented out, is it able to display all entries but just not selected?

Comment: Check the code i have posted. I have used the line that you commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
 <!-- <label>Church Groups: </label> -->
 <select name="groups[]" class="form-control mandatory" id="groups" multiple="multiple" >
     <?php
         $sql="SELECT ID,UCASE(groupName) AS groupName FROM tblgroups WHERE (congregationId=?)";
         $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($con);
         mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$congId);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
         $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                   $selected = "";
                   if(in_array($row['ID'],$groups)){ 
                       $selected = "selected"; 
                   }
                   echo '<option value='.$row['ID'].' '.$selected.'>'.$row['groupName'].'</option>';
               }
?>
</select>
```

Using your code, I have uncommented the line you commented out and introduced a variable that will be blank if the value is not in the group, otherwise it will have the value "selected", which achieves the same functionality as selected = "selelected"

Comment: This is way easier to read thanks. However, it still won't check all values from the db

Comment: Comment out the display and echo $row["ID"] alone just to confirm that all values from the database are being displayed.That way, you can examine the data and see what might be causing the problem. In your code, there is a variable **$congId**, what is its value (Its not showing where you are setting it)?

Comment: if i `echo implode("",$groups)` the results is `1, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20`

Comment: `$row['ID']` results to `18911121314151617181920`

Comment: And which row IDs are not showing inside the select?

Comment: All row IDs are being displayed. consider this if i do `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo $row['ID'] .',';` it returns `1,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,` which is the same as the result of `$group` as you saw above which means in this case all groups need to be selected

Comment: The issue is not with the php code, its just html. Tried using different bowsers? very funny suggestion, but worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assuming that your `$result` element is correct, you need something like this.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $isSel = in_array($row['ID'],$groups)? "selected" : "";

    echo "<option value=\"".$row['ID']."\" $isSel >".$row['groupName']."</option>";
}
?>
```

It is just a matter of order and linearity:

1. Populate a `$isSel` variable that contains the `selected` string only when your conditions are met
2. Print all the options, and **always** append `$isSel`. It will just contain `selected` only when it is required

---

But there are other **two issues** preventing your drop-down menu to be shown as expected:

1. Remove the square brackets `[]` from the select name. They are preventing the correct parsering of the `multiple` attribute
2. You don't need to specify `multiple="multiple"`. Just `multiple` is enough (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp)). You did also the same mistake with `selected="selected"`: just `selected` is enough

So, your `<select>` tag definition becomes

```
<select name="groupsABC" class="form-control mandatory" id="groups" multiple >
```

instead of

```
<select name="groups[]" class="form-control mandatory" id="groups" multiple="multiple" >
```

Comment: if i `echo implode("",$groups)` the results is `1, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20` so the query is working fine

Comment: The result for `$row['ID']` is `18911121314151617181920`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218960/discussion-between-nick-mackenzie-and-roberto-caboni).

Comment: Its not a strange integer, if i do `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo $row['ID'] .',';` it returns `1,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,` which is the same as the result of `$group` which means in this case all groups need to be selected

Comment: @NickMackenzie please check my edit, which solves the issue. For starters, there was a typo in my PHP code (I didn't use `$isSel` variable). But mainly, reproducing your issue, I also found the root of your issue and tested myself. 100% working solution.